# Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a Powershell through windows powershell ISE . I'm getting the following error . Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Error:

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory].
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,test1_a.ps1

code:
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client") | Out-Null
$svc = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory]::GetConfigurationServer("https://myserver.com")   <<error on this line
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for the issue.
I had to add-type via a dll like this and it is working now.

```
    Add-Type -Path “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TestAgent\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll”
$uri = "https://myserver.com:443/tfs"
$tfsConfigurationServer = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory]::GetConfigurationServer($uri)
```

Comment: If anyone knows a permanent fix instead of adding to the current session using the "Add-Type", please let me know. Basically what do I need to do to install TfsConfigurationServerFactory's dll to the machine.I have VS 2017 installed.   
 Here is the path to the file : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TestAgent\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll